# How to fix POIXMLException saying that does not have any content type rule

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am facing this issuse while reading a excel that contains hyperlinks.

I have seen many posts but none are not relevant.

Expected result is to successfully read the file but getting this exception.

Image :

[image]

Comment: Where did the file come from? Can it be opened in Excel OK? If you open and re-save in Excel, does the error go away? What version of Apache POI?

Comment: yes if i open and save it in specific format of xlsx then no issuse